# Php code is not saving user details to sql database

Tags: php, mysql

The php code below seems to run but not save into the database. Its simple yet critical enough to be a bother.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root","form2");

            if(mysql_connect_error($connect))
            {
                echo 'Failed to cnnect';
            }

            $fname=$_POST['fname'];

            if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(fname) VALUES('$fname')"))
            {
                echo ' Success';
            }else
            {
                echo ' No good!';
            }

        }
    ?>
    <form method ="POST">
        First name <input type = "text" name = "fname"></input>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value ="enter"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When should one use mysqli for security reasons (since mysql is deprecated) and how should it be used?

Comment: You should definitely read bout SQL injection:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Use PDO with Prepared, parameterized Statements. There are thousand of PDO tutorials on the internet. One would be Jay Blanchard's (he's also on SO spreading PDO) http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: Not helping, view the given code.